# My previous order is overwritten by the latest order

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to loop the code to let the user add another item.

My task is to "develop a program that will update stock levels following an order. In the stock file include a current stock level, re-order level and target stock level. The program should, when instructed to do so, calculate which products are out of stock or below the re-order level and create a file. This file will contain orders of re-stocking that will bring the current stock level of these products up to the target stock level". I have done all of this, but I am struggling to add the while loop in case the user wishes to add another item to their order.

[This is the stock file (this is named product information in the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7r8H.png)

[This is the updated stock file when I run the code (this is named Blank file in the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9TX6.png)

[This is the text file which contains orders for restocking (this is named Reorders in the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uGhJ.png)

This is my code:

```
import csv
option='yes'
while option=='yes':
    data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
    purchase=csv.reader(data)
    blank=open('Blank file.csv', 'wt', newline='')
    blank_write=csv.writer(blank)
    reorder=open('Reorders.txt', 'wt')
    user_orders=[]
    order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
    quantity=int(input('Please enter the amount of this product you want to buy: '))
    for row in purchase:
        GTIN=row[0]
        item=row[1]
        price=row[2]
        stock=row[3]
        reorder_level=row[4]
        target_stock=row[5]
        if order==GTIN:
            stock=int(stock)-quantity
        blank_write.writerows([[GTIN,item,price,stock,reorder_level,target_stock]])
    data.close()
    blank.close()
    blank2=open('Blank file.csv', 'rt')
    blank_write2=csv.reader(blank2)
    choice=input('Please enter yes to check the current stock levels: ')
    if choice=='yes':
        for row in blank_write2:
            GTIN=row[0]
            item=row[1]
            price=row[2]
            stock=int(row[3])
            reorder_level=int(row[4])
            target_stock=int(row[5])
            if stock<=reorder_level:
                amount_to_restock=target_stock-stock
                reorder_file=('{} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(row[0]+'   ', row[1]+'   ', '{:10.2f}'.format(float(row[2]))+'   ', str(stock)+'   ', str(reorder_level)+'   ', str(target_stock)+'   ', str(amount_to_restock)))
                reorder.write(reorder_file)
    option=input('Would you like to add another item: ')
    if option=='no':
        blank2.close()
        reorder.close()
```

If I enter yes to "Would you like to add another item:" the latest product overwrites the first one that I ordered. This means that only the latest product is written onto the CSV file. I would like the programme to write both products onto the CSV file.

Thanks

Comment: Try opening your files using append mode, `a`, instead of write mode, `w`. Alternatively, store all of your data in an intermediary data structure, and only write the data to file exactly once after the user has completely finished entering data.

Comment: I get the append bit but on what file do I write it on? Text or CSV?